# Structurally Enforcing No Red Children Of Red Node

Tags: haskell, red-black-tree, recursive-datastructures

While studying [Learn You A Haskell For Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) and [Purely Functional Data Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504), I thought to try to reimplement a [Red Black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) while trying to structurally enforce another tree invariant.

Paraphrasing Okasaki's code, his node looks something like this:

```
import Data.Maybe

data Color = Red | Black

data Node a = Node {
    value :: a,
    color :: Color,
    leftChild :: Maybe (Node a),
    rightChild :: Maybe (Node a)}
```

One of the properties of a red black tree is that [a red node cannot have a direct-child red node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Properties), so I tried to encode this as the following:

```
import Data.Either

data BlackNode a = BlackNode {
    value :: a,
    leftChild :: Maybe (Either (BlackNode a) (RedNode a)),
    rightChild :: Maybe (Either (BlackNode a) (RedNode a))}
data RedNode a = RedNode {
    value :: a,
    leftChild :: Maybe (BlackNode a),
    rightChild :: Maybe (BlackNode a)}
```

This outputs the errors:

```
Multiple declarations of `rightChild'
Declared at: :4:5
             :8:5


Multiple declarations of `leftChild'
Declared at: :3:5
             :7:5


Multiple declarations of `value'
Declared at: :2:5
             :6:5
```

I've tried several modifications of the previous code, but they all fail compilation. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Sadly, you can't name two fields of two different types in the same way. Try naming them `blackValue,..,blackRightChild` and similarly for the red counterparts.

Comment: @chi May the chi be with you! That worked! I'm amazed that Haskell has this restriction - would never have guessed. Would you perhaps write that as an answer? I've spent several hours playing around with this and searching all over the internet - maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: While you certainly can enforce the "no red node with a red child" invariant, it turns out that enforcing the full complement of red-black tree invariants without breaking performance is really hard. After you've skimmed papers about it, I suspect you'll come to the same conclusion I did--you're generally better off biting the bullet and using 2-3-4 trees instead.

Comment: There's actually a new GHC feature that lifts this restriction in the upcoming 8.0 release.

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks for your comment. If you'd care to share the links, I'd appreciate it. Is it at all possible to enforce everything? I'm at loss how to enforce the basic search-tree invariant (namely that the left subtree's keys are \leq, and the right's are \geq).

Comment: @AmiTavory, in Haskell, it will be very hard to enforce the order invariants, inefficiently, and for natural-number keys. I was actually referring only to the full shape invariants. A fully dependently typed language would make enforcing the order invariants easier and more useful.

Comment: I don't happen to have links on hand. I last looked at the articles several years ago. I seem to remember there being a couple of them. In each case, the authors started out talking big, but ended up having to perform some horribly expensive operation that couldn't be amortized properly in a persistent context.

Comment: Btw, you may be interested in [Stephanie Weirich's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhWMhTjQzsU) where she does just that.

Comment: @gallais Many thanks for the link!

Comment: There has been a simple implementation in the ghc testsuite for years fwiw https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/testsuite/tests/polykinds/RedBlack.hs I'm not sure it gets all the desired invariants, and it's probably slow...

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different record types must have distinct field names. E.g., this is not allowed:

```
data A = A { field :: Int }
data B = B { field :: Char }
```

while this is OK:

```
data A = A { aField :: Int }
data B = B { bField :: Char }
```

The former would attempt to define two projections

```
field :: A -> Int
field :: B -> Char
```

but, alas, we can't have a name with two types. (At least, not so easily...)
This issue is not present in OOP languages, where field names can never be used on their own, but they must be immediately applied to some object, as in `object.field` -- which is unambiguous, provided we already know the type of `object`. Haskell allows standalone projections, making things more complicated here.

The latter approach instead defines

```
aField :: A -> Int
bField :: B -> Char
```

and avoids the issue.

As @dfeuer comments above, GHC 8.0 will likely relax this constraint.